# Angular1.3: $compile html inside a file link?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, frontend, angular-directive

I would really appreciate some advice on this.
I have the below compile operator inside the link function of my directive:

```
element.replaceWith($compile(
            '<div>Big chunk' +
            'of html</div>'  +
            )(scope));
```

Is there a cleaner way to replace the above html inside a string with a link to a file instead? Also considering that the above line is called many times (30-40+ times inside an ng-repeat), would there be any performance hits from http requests to the file/ would it be against best practices to link to an actual file?

Comment: Did you consider using `ng-bind-template` or `ng-include`?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `templateUrl` property of a directive. Furthermore when linked to a server side request angular has a service called the `$templateCache` which will cause any html that is loaded will be compiled and stored there so there is no overhead outside of the single request to the server to get your large HTML.

`$templateCache`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

This will automatically get populated as part of any directive. So you can just go ahead and use it.